# location subdirectory nginx with rewrite drupal

Tags: nginx, drupal-7

I have this configuration of nginx :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    location = / {
            root /var/www/example.com;
            index index.php;
    }

    location / {
            root   /var/www/example.com/Drupal;
            index  index.php index.html;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                    rewrite  ^(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
                    break;
            }

            if (!-d $request_filename) {
                    rewrite  ^(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
                    break;
            }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

            set $php_root /var/www/example.com/Drupal;

            if ($request_uri ~ ^/MassMail) {
                    set $php_root /var/www/example.com/MassMail;
            }

            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    }
```

I have 2 app in php :

- the first in /var/www/example.com/MassMail
- the second in /var/www/example.com/Drupal (a Drupal blog)

my server serve right the two URL

example.com/ --> drupal blog

example.com/MassMail --> other app

but it doesn't serve the image or the JavaScript ... (error 404)

for serve img etc i have tested lot of thing like this (for example ...) :

```
    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
           expires         30d;
            access_log      off;
    }
```

maybe missing a root directory for, but which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You php thinks that MassMail installed in the / (root), try to add second location for staitc files:

```
location ~* ^/MassMail.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
           expires         30d;
            access_log      off;
           root /var/www/xxx.com/MassMail;
}
```

**Configuration #2**

```
location ~* ^/(.*)/.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
  expires         30d;
     access_log      off;
   root /var/www/xxx.com/$1;
}
```

**Configuration #3**

Place each app configuration in special file(example for MassMail):

*applications/massmail.conf*:

```
  location ~ \.php$ {

            set $php_root /var/www/xxx.com/Drupal;

            if ($request_uri ~ ^/MassMail) {
                    set $php_root /var/www/xxx.com/MassMail;
            }

   location ~* ^/MassMail.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
           expires         30d;
            access_log      off;
           root /var/www/xxx.com/MassMail;
   }
```

*nginx.conf*:

```
.....
include applications/massmail.conf;
```

Comment: thank you Sergei ! actually yes it works ... but i have 2 locations of static content for 2 apps ... if i have 75 apps ? 75 locations of static content ?? there is no generic way for this stuff ??

Comment: Well actually you coud implement second configuration, but it's not a good practice. The better way is using for each application special file with config(see example #3)